# image position problem

Tags: graphics, positioning

I have a problem with images positioning.
I dont know why but latex puts the last figure on a new page.
I want it all at the same page.
And I cant find what is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcounter{priklad}
\newenvironment{priklad}
{\refstepcounter{priklad}
\medskip

\textbf{Příklad \thepriklad .\ }}

\lhead{TEXT}

\pagestyle{fancy}

    \begin{document}

\begin{priklad}
text-n-1
\end{priklad}

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{11.eps}}
\hspace{10pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{16.eps}}
\hspace{10pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{23.eps}}
\hspace{10pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{14.eps}}
\hspace{10pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{15.eps}}
\hspace{10pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{12.eps}}
\end{figure}

\begin{priklad}
text-n-2
\end{priklad}
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\includegraphics[height=1.8cm]{E.eps}
\hspace{20pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{Eb.eps}}
\hspace{8pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{Eano.eps}}
\hspace{8pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{Ec.eps}}
\hspace{8pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{Ed.eps}}
\hspace{8pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{Ee.eps}}
\end{figure}

\begin{priklad}
text-n-3
\end{priklad}

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\includegraphics[height=2.7cm]{7.eps}
\hspace{8pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{7b.eps}}
\hspace{0pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{7d.eps}}
\hspace{2pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{7ano.eps}}
\hspace{4pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{7c.eps}}
\end{figure}

\begin{priklad}
text-n-4
\end{priklad}

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\includegraphics[height=4.2cm]{2u.eps}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.9cm]{2a.eps}}
\hspace{3pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.9cm]{2b.eps}}
\hspace{3pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.9cm]{2c.eps}}
\hspace{3pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.9cm]{2d.eps}}
\hspace{3pt}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.9cm]{2e.eps}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Would anyone know what may cause my problem?

Comment: article class has \setcounter{totalnumber}{3}  so only allows three floats per text page by default, but you can reset that....

Comment: You are missing the second argument of `\newenvironment` (defining the end code) it is not an error as it takes the blank line you have before `\lhead` as the argument so defines teh end code to be `\par`

Comment: since you have no captions, and don't want the images to move why are you using figure and subfigre at all, not just `\includegraphics`?

Answer (score 2):

article class has

```
\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
```

so only allows three floats per text page by default, but you can reset that, however more easily you could use `[!htbp]` where the `!` signifies that the numeric constraints are to be ignored.